# How to run Behave tests using a remote interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, vagrant, pycharm, remote-debugging, python-behave

I have my Vagrant instance properly setup and working for running and debugging my project remotely , but I have been unable to get the Behave tests working at all .

I get
`Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.`

with these set in the Behave Run/Debug Configuration
`'Feature files or folders' = features
'Python Interpreter' = Remote Python 2.7.6 Vagrant VM ...'`

I get the same result when properly setting the working directory to either the project's local or remote path , and/or adding a path mapping to the project root . IE
`'Working directory' = /vagrant ( remote project path )
'Path mappings' = /home/project=/vagrant`

If I set an incorrect path I always get a path doesn't exist AssertionError .

Could someone demonstrate a working configuration for this type of scenario ?